# Read both internal and external property file using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
I have a spring boot application jar

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    @PropertySource({"classpath:1.properties","classpath:2.properties"})
    public class MyClass {
//My class

    }
```

1.properties  is in src/main/resources
  2.properties is in server location project location

```
| MyClass.jar
| config
        | 2.properties
```

But I am getting file not found for 2.properties when starting the application.Please let me know what I could be missing here.

Comment: If your `2.properties` file is outside of the jar then you're not going to find it on the classpath

Comment: I have kept it inside a config folder which is parallel to the jar. So that config folder also should be available in class path right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comment, your `2.properties` file is not under your `classpath`. You can only use `classpath` if your file really exists in your `jar` or `war`.

To get the `2.properties` you should use the command `file:` instead of `classpath:`.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:1.properties","file:${application_home}2.properties")
```

I am not quite sure if its still necessary to have an OS environment variable or a system property to set the path to your property file. In this case I named it `application_home`.

Comment: I have kept it inside a config folder which is parallel to the jar. So that config folder also should be available in class path right?